# My nested attributes are not passing through the strong Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a form for a delivery order that contains a form for a meal inside of it. A meal is made up of items, which are also objects. The form for a delivery looks as so...

```
<%= form_for @delivery do | f | %>
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <f.text_field :address $>
  <% if @meal != nil %>
    <% meal = @meal %>
  <% else %>
    <% meal = Meal.new %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for meal %>
    <%= render partial: "meals/form", locals: {selected_meal: meal} %> 
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Continue" %>
<% end %>
```

and the form for the meal looks as so

```
  <label>Meal Name: (Optional) </label>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <br>
  <h4>-----------Pizzas------------</h4>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :meal_item, Item.pizza_items, :id, :show %>
  <br>
  <h4>-------Cold Sandwiches-------</h4>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :meal_item, Item.cold_items, :id, :show %>
  <br>
  <h4>-------Hot Sandwiches-------</h4>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :meal_item, Item.hot_items, :id, :show %>
  <br>
  <h4>-----------Salads-----------</h4>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :meal_item, Item.salad_items, :id, :show %>
  <br>
  <h4>------------Pastas------------</h4>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :meal_item, Item.hot_items, :id, :show %>
  <br>
  <h4>-----------Chicken-----------</h4>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :meal_item, Item.hot_items, :id, :show %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Continue" %>
<% end %>
```

When the delivery form with the nested meal form is passed, it goes to the delivery # confirm action, and with the strong param, it looks like this...

```
def confirm
    binding.pry
    @delivery = Delivery.new()
    if (SessionHelpers.is_logged_in?(session))
      @credit = SessionHelpers.current_user(session).credit
    end
end

private

def delivery_params
  params.require(:delivery).permit(:address, :order_user_id, :total_price, :delivered, meal_attributes: [:name, items:[]])
end
```

Whenever the form is passed, the `delivery_params` only has the address passed, none of the meal attributes go through, yet they exist in the regular params. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you setup `accepts_nested_attributes`?

Comment: Yes, my Delivery Class belongs_to meal and also accepts_nested_attributes_for :meal

Answer (score 1):

Probably coming from how you call your nested form.
Maybe try smething like :

```
<%= f.fields_for :meal do |meal_f| %>
```

And in your partial :

```
<%= meal_f.text_field :name %>
```

Comment: That's progress, now when I see what the params are inside of pry, it now says `unpermitted parameter: :meal` which it did not say before

Comment: Try with `meal` as you have declared it just before the nested form. But just seen you have replied to eyeslandic that delivery was a child of meal. Nested form should be top bottom (at least the way I know them) : you ask details for the parent first then any child if needed through a nested form...